# vuejs how to access a ref inside a child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to vuejs and not very experienced in JavaScript. I use Vue3 in Laravel

I have a child component which exposes a ref on an input like this

```
<input 
    v-model="raw_input" 
    ref="raw"  
    @input="checkLength(limit)" 
    @keydown="enterNumbers($event)" 
    type="number" 
/>

const raw = ref('');
defineExpose({
    raw
})
```

In the parent

```
<template lang="">
    <PageComponent title="Dashboard">
    <SmartVolumeInputVue ref="svi" />
    <div class="mt-16 border  h-8">
    {{ val }}
    </div>
    </PageComponent>
</template>

<script setup>
import PageComponent from "../components/PageComponent.vue"
import SmartVolumeInputVue from "../components/customInputs/SmartVolumeInput.vue";import { computed, ref } from "vue";

const svi = ref(null)
//let val=svi
//let val=svi.raw
let val=svi.raw.value
</script>
```

At the bottom of the script there are 3 lines (I only uncomment one at a time)
The first displays this in the template

```
{ "raw": "[object HTMLInputElement]" }
```

The second displays nothing

And the third reports an error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: svi.raw is undefined

I need some help to get the value of the referenced input in the child component.

Comment: do you want to make a two way binding?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the ref on the element? Or only the value?

If not, just expose the value like this: [Live example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
// App.vue
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import SmartVolumeInputVue from './SmartVolumeInput.vue'
const svi = ref()
</script>

<template>
    <SmartVolumeInputVue ref="svi" />
  <div>
    {{svi?.raw_input}}
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
// SmartVolumeInput.vue
<script setup>
import { ref, defineExpose } from 'vue'
const raw_input = ref(123)
defineExpose({
  raw_input
})
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model.number="raw_input" type="number" />
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Fully absorbed by the job I completely forget that I posted this question and I must apologize for not having acknowledged it. I used a solution based on event that seems less elegant. i will give your solution a try. Thank you again

Comment: For some reason I was not able to understand the example in the VueJS documentation. This example here helped me a lot, so thanks for that!